# .htaccess Custom Redirection Rule

Tags: php, .htaccess, server

I want a custom redirection rule to add in the .htaccess file for many of existing URLs of files on our server already added in our system which are impossible to be changed everywhere.

Existing URL: http://oldurl.com/oldfolder/File.pdf

New URL: http://newurl.com/File.pdf

The file names have both capital and small letters (upper and lower case) so need to be taken care of. Please help.

My website is on WordPress. I tried many plugins but only one plugin gave me a partial result. It changed the url structure but changed the upper case letter to lowercase which means the files are not accessible.

Comment: Welcome! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+).pdf/$ http://oldurl.com/oldfolder/$1 [NC,L]
```

`RewriteCond -f` this condition means if the file exist

`RewriteRule` starting from `/` file_name.pdf ending with `/`

Comment: Did u check the change in domain name? Please suggest the complete code to be added in .htaccess file.